# iTunes keeps creating wakeuptoken.info file. How to stop that?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, itunes-11

Lately for some reason iTunes 11 started creating wakeuptoken.info file on my D:\

It never did that before and if I delete that file iTunes seems to work fine.

What is that file for?

Why is it being created on my D:\ and not somewhere in my profile dir/iTune's dirs?